# What consume the computer memory in Hadoop YARN?

Tags: hadoop, memory, service, daemon, hadoop-yarn

I want to ask about hadoop YARN. For example before I start the daemon I have free memory "X" MB, so after I do start-all.sh to start the daemon, my free memory become "Y" MB. So I want to know in particular what service or something that consume my node memory?

Thanks all....

Answer (score 0):

start-all.sh script  starts the HDFS daemons: NameNode and DataNode, and YARN daemons: ResourceManager and Nodemanager. Enter  the "jps" command, this will list all the running java processes. These daemons consume your CPU Memory.

Comment: oooooo thanks, can I ask you again. Is configuration on yarn-site.xml will consume the memory after start-all.sh command?